# Matching post author to post in React from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and I have successfully mapped the post titles to a div on the page. I also need to take the "userid" from the posts and get the user's name from the users state and add it to a

on the div.
I can send the userid to a function which is set to return the corresponding user but it does not show up on the page. I would appreciate a review of my code to see where I am going wrong. I can log out to the console the right user but it doesn't show up on the HTML. The second

in the  section is the one that is not populating I would need to do that on comments as well later on so for now I just assigned a static innerHTML for that. here is my code that I have. Thanks in advance.

```
export default function Posts(name) {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
    // get Posts
useEffect(() => {
    getPosts()
        .then(items => {
            setPosts(items)
        })
    // Get all Users
    getUsers()
        .then(users => {
            setUsers(users)
        })
    // Get all comments
    getComments()
    .then(comments =>{
        setComments(comments)
    })
    
}, [])

// get individual user by userId
const getPostAuthor = (userid)=> {
     users.filter((item) =>{
        if ( item.id === userid){
            console.log(item.name)
            return item.name
        }
     })
    }
return ( <PostsSection> {
            posts.map(item => <Post><PostTitle key ={ item.title }> { item.title } </PostTitle><PostBody key={item.body}>{item.body}</PostBody><PostFooter><p>comments:4</p><p>{getPostAuthor(item.userId)}</p></PostFooter></Post>)}
        </PostsSection> )
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`users.filter` is returning `item.name`, but `getPostAuthor()` does not return anything. You could put a `return` before your `users.filter` function but since `Array.filter()` returns an array and you want one user I'd expect that is not what you want. You could instead try [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did go ahead and use Array.find and got back the user for each post what I am not getting is for it to show up on the html on the page. The console.log show the users coming back but just an empty <p> tag on the page.

Comment: You will also need a `return` inside your `posts.map()`. Like this: `posts.map(item => return ( <Post>. . .`